# unable to Constract Currentsession in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

i am integrate hibernate with spring mvc and Autowired Session factory like below coding

```
@Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Usermaster> getUserList() {

        Session currentSession=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<Usermaster> theq=currentSession.createQuery("from Usermaster",Usermaster.class);
        List<Usermaster> user=theq.getResultList();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return user;
    }
```

but getting error like this below:

```
org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl - HHH000302: Unable to construct current session context [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.buildCurrentSessionContext(SessionFactoryImpl.java:970)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:189)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:350)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1842)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/jta/platform/spi/JtaPlatform
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.<init>(SpringSessionContext.java:56)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 47 more
```

my servlet-context.xmlcoding is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<beans:property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<beans:property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/open_tracket?useSSL=false"/>
<beans:property name="user" value="root"/>
<beans:property name="password" value="12345"/> 
<beans:property name="initialPoolSize" value="5"/>
<beans:property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
<beans:property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
<beans:property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000"/>
</beans:bean>
<!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<beans:property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
<beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ar.entity"/>
<beans:property name="hibernateProperties">

<beans:props>
<beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
</beans:prop>
<beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
</beans:props>
</beans:property>
</beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ar" />



</beans:beans>
```

where all the details of connections is right ,project is running ok, only getting error for hibernate , where Usermaster is a pojo file , how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Hibernate 4.3.x, the JtaPlatform class is refactored to a new package. To fix it, downgrade Hibernate to 4.2.x or older, or upgrade the Spring framework.

Tested on my development environment, here are the version that works :

Spring 3.2.8.RELEASE
Hibernate 4.2.11.Final

or

To fix it,you need to upgrade your spring version to 4.1.x latest release.Below is pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

Which version of Hibernate and Spring are in your dependencies?

Comment: its working after updated pom.xml, than you so much. :)